# How to link object file produced by ocamlopt to create executable?

Tags: ocaml

I can take the following ocaml module `test.ml` and compile it with `ocamlopt`

```
(* test.ml *)
Printf.printf "hi\n"
```

By doing

```
$ ocamlopt -o test.native test.ml
$ ./test.native
hi
```

I can also compile it without linking.

```
$ ocamlopt -o test.o -c test.ml
$ ls
test.cmi        test.cmx        test.ml         test.o
```

However, if I then try to link the object I just created with the OCaml runtime to get an executable, no files are created (even though `ocamlopt` exits normally)

```
$ ocamlopt -o test.native test.o
$ ls
test.cmi        test.cmx        test.ml         test.o
```

How do I direct `ocamlopt` to link in the OCaml runtime and produce an executable "as if" I had run `ocamlopt -o test.native test.ml`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to give the `.cmx` file to the compiler, not the `.o` file.

```
$ ocamlopt -o test.native test.cmx
$ ./test.native
hi
```

Comment: Interesting... Why is the `.o` file produced at all then?

Comment: The .o file has the native code. The .cmx file has the OCaml metadata. The compiler expects a .cmx file when the original code was OCaml, and a .o file when the original code was some other language (usually C). When you specify a .cmx file, the compiler finds the .o file automatically.

Comment: I see... so the `ocamlopt` invocation depends on the existence of `test.o` ... but you don't pass it on the command line. ... Is there a way to make `ocamlopt` a bit stricter (so it'll fail more loudly rather than producing nothing)?

Comment: You might want to use some [build automation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Build_automation) tool (like [ninja](http://ninja-build.org/), `ocamlbuild`, `make`, `omake` ...)

Comment: Aha, I get it. I don't know a way to get ocamlopt to complain. But you could easily argue that the current behavior is a bug. It might be good to report it. Note that this command behaves similarly: `ocamlopt -o abc.native` (with no objects or sources given).